# Insert/delete line to a file if pattern match

Tags: ruby

[this is a ruby problem]

- if line matching pattern exists => insert RIGHT after the a predefined variable(line)
- if line matching pattern exists AND also line that contains that predefined variable => delete this line

Given file:
ldap_config.conf

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
ldap_filters = yes
line..M
line..N
```

test_add_del.rb

```
users = %w/user1 user2 user3/
users.length == 1 ? _var = “(#{users[0]})” : _var = ‘(|’ + users.map{|u| “(#{u})”}.join + ‘)’
f = File.open(“ldap_config.conf”).read

f.each_line do |line|
    if  line.match(/ldap_filter_users/)
            f.gsub!(/\sldap_filter_users\s+=.*$/, '#')
            File.write("ldap_config.conf", f)
    elsif line.match(/ldap_filters =/)
            f.gsub!(/ldap_filters = yes/, "ldap_filters = yes\n ldap_filter_users = "+_var)
            File.write("ldap_config.conf", f)

    end
end
```

NOW:

if I runt 1st time the script get this output =>

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
ldap_filters = yes
ldap_filter_users = (|(user1)(user2)(user3))
line..M
line..N
```

…and if i runt it 2nd time get this output =>

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
ldap_filters = yes
#
#
line..M
line..N
```

As my ruby skills are quite low, a better example/explanation would be highly appreciate.

P.S.

as expected result:

…and if i runt it 2nd time should get this output =>

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
ldap_filters = yes
line..M
line..N
```

Comment: it is part of a bigger puppet deploy; this is just the part that is handling this  issue insert/delete is match

Comment: we also need a desired output to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the crucial problem with your code is that it does a
global replace and writes the output while it iterates through all lines.

This should produce the desired output

```
users = %w/user1 user2 user3/
_var = users.map { |u| "(#{u})" }.join
_var = "(|#{_var})" if users.length > 1
f = File.open("ldap_config.conf").read

changed = 
  if f.match(/ldap_filter_users/)
    f.gsub!(/ldap_filter_users\s+=.*$\n/, '') 
  elsif f.match(/ldap_filters =/)
    f.gsub!(/ldap_filters = yes/, "ldap_filters = yes\nldap_filter_users = #{_var}")
  end

File.write("ldap_config.conf", f) if changed
```

Comment: Thanks @periswon ;  Now I've understand the code better, but still have to say ruby documentation is quite week in describing better file content manipulation....

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely follow what you're going for, or what is going wrong currently, but here are some things that *might* be your issue:

In a ruby regex, ^ and $ match the start/end of the string, not the end of a line. You probably want to use \A and \Z instead, to match line endings.

You're doing a mix of line-oriented processing and file-level processing. Maybe that works? But confusing. I'd stick with one or the other. I *think* you don't need to iterate over the lines at all. You can just test for:

```
f.match(/\Aldap_filter_users\Z/)
```

Also, "f" looks like a file handle. Try "conf" or something instead. (style)

Do you want the lines with only "#" in the output?  If not, change this line:

```
conf.gsub!(/\Aldap_filter_users\s+=.*\Z/, '#')
```

to this:

```
conf.gsub!(/\Aldap_filter_users\s+=.*\Z/, '')
```

And most of all, you're writing the whole file once for line of the file. You'll be left with whatever got written on the last pass through the file. This is most likely at least part of the problem you're seeing.

Something like this might fix it, or at least make the issue easier to trace through.

```
users = %w/user1 user2 user3/

if users.length == 1 
  user_list = "(#{users[0]})"
else
  user_list = '(|' + users.map{|u| "(#{u})"}.join + ')'
end

conf = File.open("ldap_config.conf").read

if conf.match(/\Aldap_filter_users\Z/)
  conf.gsub!(/\Aldap_filter_users\s+=.*\Z/, '#')  
elsif line.match(/\Aldap_filters =/)
  conf.gsub!(/\Aldap_filters = yes\Z/, "ldap_filters = yes\n ldap_filter_users = #{user_list}")        
end

File.write("ldap_config.conf", conf)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate both answers :)